# TypeError: object of type 'Bidirectional' has no len()

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

This is the code I'm running:

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from tqdm import tqdm, trange
   import unicodedata

   from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
   from keras.utils import to_categorical
   from keras.models import Model
   from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
   from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Embedding, Dense, TimeDistributed, Dropout, 
   Bidirectional

   # Defining Constants

   # Maximum length of text sentences
   MAXLEN = 180
   # Number of LSTM units
   LSTM_N = 150
   # batch size
   BS=48

   input = Input(shape=(MAXLEN,))

   model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=MAXLEN, input_length=MAXLEN)(input)

   model = Dropout(0.2)(model)

   model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=LSTM_N, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)

   out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(model)  # softmax output layer

   model = Model(input, out)

   model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
   history = model.fit(X, np.array(y), batch_size=BS, epochs=2, validation_split=0.05, verbose=1)
```

I'm running a `bidirectional LSTM`. But this error is appearing:

> TypeError: object of type 'Bidirectional' has no len()

What's wrong in this code? Please help.

Comment: I get the impression that there's some code missing from the end. Could you add the rest of the code and the full traceback?

Comment: @simon I've added the rest of code. Now can you tell what's wrong with this?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when using the code you wrote. Could you provide a more detailed error message? A trace back might help finding out what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing consistent imports. Simply change,

```
from keras.models import Model
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing from

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
```

to

```
from keras.layers import Input
```

solved my issue.